# Delete based on LIKE and Wildcard from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the query I'm trying so you get the idea of what I am trying to do. I am trying to use the wildcard on the other field so they match based on similarity and not exact match because for example in the `wr_report_sites` table there will be an entry of `Chicago`, where are in the `sites` table the entry will be `Chicago`, IL. I just need to match based on the fact that both contain `Chicago`.

```
DELETE wr FROM WR_reported_Sites wr
    INNER JOIN sites s
    ON wr.Site_Name LIKE %s.Site_Name%
```

Comment: Please edit the question and include the tables referenced and sample data.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be this?

```
    DELETE FROM WR_reported_Sites 
    WHERE   Site_Name IN (SELECT wr.Site_Name FROM R_reported_Sites wr INNER                 
    JOIN sites s ON wr.Site_Name LIKE '%' + s.Site_Name+ '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...the wr_report_sites table there will be an entry of Chicago, where
> are in the sites table the entry will be Chicago, IL...

The condition in the `ON` clause should be:

```
ON s.Site_Name LIKE CONCAT('%', wr.Site_Name, '%')
```

because `wr.Site_Name` is contained in `s.Site_Name`.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly it seems. And I'm learning more and more about proper syntax. Thank you very much.

Comment: @doctorO20 fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.